# node.js readline: "TypeError: rl is not iterable"

Tags: node.js, readline

When I try to run my code I get this error:

```
file:///C:/Users/rb03/Documents/Testing/connect.js:27
for (const line of rl) {
                   ^

TypeError: rl is not iterable
    at file:///C:/Users/rb03/Documents/Testing/connect.js:27:24
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:777:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:514:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ClientHandshake.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:121:14)
    at ClientHandshake.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at ClientHandshake.execute (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:44:10)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\rb03\Documents\Testing\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
```

My code is as follows:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected!');

    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: fs.createReadStream('./Logs/Outputs/split.lines.txt') });

    let total = 0;
    let buff = [];
    for (const line of rl) {
        buff.push([line]);
        total++;
        if (buff.length % 2000 === 0) {
            connection.query("INSERT INTO test (line, timestamp, errortype) VALUES ?");
            console.log(total);
            buff = [];
        };
    };

    if (buff.length > 0) {
        connection.query("INSERT INTO test (line, timestamp, errortype) VALUES ?");
        console.log(total);
    };

    connection.end();
});
```

Anyone got any idea what to do? Google shows nothing for "rl is not iterable", only for "rl is not async iterable"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it means that there is a problem with your `for` loop in regards to the file.
What does `split.lines.txt` look like?

Comment: It needs to be `for await (const line of rl)` and this needs to be in an `async` function.  You are missing the `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do iteration, it needs to be:

```
for await (const line of rl)
```

and this needs to be in an `async` function.  You are missing the `await`.

`rl` has an `asyncIterator`, but not a regular iterator so you need the `await` to get the iteration to work.

---

If you don't want to iterate, you can use regular events and listen for the `line` event.

```
rl.on('line', line => {
   // process line here
});
```

Comment: running it in an async function just gives it a syntaxerror saying "Unexpected reserved word"

Comment: What version of nodejs are you running?  And, you may have to add to an edit of your question, what code you're trying that isn't working because we can't debug code we can't see.  You can see an example for how the `for` loop works [here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator).

Comment: The code i posted in here is basically the entire code except for importing mysql, readline and fs, and my database connection which is a standard mysql.createconnection

Comment: @mirairoses - I'm saying you aren't showing what code you tried with `for await (const line of rl)` so we can't debug your attempt to use that.  That structure will work just fine if you have the right version of nodejs and you use it correctly.

Comment: I can't really edit my question because Stack Overflow says "add more details" so here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WQQ8mmTw

Comment: @mirairoses - That's because the containing function is not marked `async`.  `await` can only be used inside of `async` functions.  You will note my answer mentions this also.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute a code for each line of input, you can use the `line` event.

```js
rl.on('line', (input) => {
  console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
});
```

See the [Readline documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line).

EDIT: There is an [`asyncIterator` symbol](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_symbol_asynciterator) that can be used to iterate over `Readline.Interface`. However, instead of a regular `for...of` loop, it requires an `for await...of` loop.

```js
for await (const line of rl) {
  console.log(`Received: ${line}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working fine now.